# Выделить жирным фрагменты текста

Tags: php, preg_replace

Здравствуйте.

Как можно выделить (поместить между тегами `<b></b>`) слова, над которыми есть звездочки, а после звездочек идут запятые, в данном случае `<b>английский*</b>` и `<b>русский*</b>`?

```
чешский, датский, голландский, английский*, финский, французский, немецкий, венгерский, итальянский, японский, корейский, норвежский, польский, португальский, бразильский португальский, румынский, русский*, упрощенный китайский, испанский, шведский, тайский, традиционный китайский, турецкий, болгарский, украинский
*озвучивание доступно на этих языках
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input = 'чешский, датский, голландский, английский*, финский, французский, немецкий, венгерский, итальянский, японский, корейский, норвежский, польский, португальский, бразильский португальский, румынский, русский*, упрощенный китайский, испанский, шведский, тайский, традиционный китайский, турецкий, болгарский, украинский *озвучивание доступно на этих языках';

echo preg_replace('/([\w-]+)\s*\*/u', '<b>$1</b>', $input);
```

Можете посмотреть результат [здесь](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3300772a60496437fd8449dc0a85dc7362f336e2).

Answer (score 0):

Вас интересует именно регулярка? Я не особо их люблю.
Можно и так:

```
$mas = explode(", ", $string); // получаем массив со всеми языками
foreach ($mas as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos(value, '*')
        $mas[$key] = "<b>" . $value . "</b>";
}
$string = implode(", ", $mas);
```